# in react-native, how to force re-render of stateless functional component

Tags: react-native

In regular React, there is a way to force re-renders of stateless functional components with top-level API `ReactDOM.render()`.

Is there a way to force re-render of a stateless functional component in react-native?

Comment: this.forceUpdate() method might be what you are looking for

Comment: can you give me an example of how you would use `this.forceUpdate()` in a stateless functional component? I don't get how that is possible. @BurakKarasoy

Answer (score 2):

say your component is `myComp`,

`myComp.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(myComp)`

it is strongly discouraged to use this in real time application, due to the nature of stateless component are suppose to be 'stateless' and its concerns is solely to one time render its content.